# Как реализовать многостраничный API?

Tags: api, rest

Имеется REST (like) API, который возвращает список результатов. Результаты получаются из SQL запроса. Необходимо реализовать пэйджинг, т.е. возможность возвращать только определенное количество элементов начиная с запрошенного.

Решение "в лоб" - каждый раз выполнять запрос и отсчитывать необходимые записи из курсора, работает крайне медленно.

Кэширование результатов в API и хранение до следующего вызова нарушает принцип независимости состояния (statelessness).

Какие еще подходы к реализации данного функционала можно посоветовать?

База данных - PostgreSQL.

Comment: Хмм а сам SQL запрос адаптировать?Ограничить количество результатов?

Comment: Типа  SELECT * FROM data_set WHERE name = 'test' LIMIT 10; ?

Comment: Проблема в отсутствии в результате уникального ключа. Так что 10 первых записей вернуть можно, а вот следующие 10 - уже нет.

Comment: Вопрос не скромный само апи на jave?Уточню идею сеты могут перебирать записи сохраняя состяние...

Comment: На Mule / RAML.

Comment: Гонять (между клиентом и сервером) последний полученный идентификатор нет желания?По сути это канонический подход(в моем понимании)

Comment: Так а что за идентификатор? Вообще, я подумал, что возможно комбинация всех полей даст уникальный ключ, но это будет как бы уловка. Я подозреваю, надо копать где-то в направлении кэширования в PG.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38652/discussion-between-peter-slusar-and-spoonboy).